# C# UInt vs Cpp DWORD conflict with negative values

Tags: c#, dword, uint32

C++: `DWORD dwState = (DWORD)-1;`

Here there is no issues.

C#: `uint state = -1`;

Here, uint or UInt32 which is considered to be the equivalent of DWORD cannot have a negative value and it throws below exception.

**Value was either too large or too small for a UInt32**

I have a code which reads this value (which is stored in DB) both from cpp and c# programs.
Cpp marks invalid state as -1. Hence I'm unable to read it from C# front with uint type. 
I cannot change this type in c++ program. Apart from -1, cpp may write any value between 0-65536 for variable.

How can I handle it from C# front!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I handle it from C# front!?

You can use the [`unchecked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8.aspx) operator for the constant assignment:

```
uint state = unchecked((uint) -1);
```

From the C# spec section 7.6.12:

> The `checked` and `unchecked` operators are used to control the *overflow checking context* for integral-type arithmetic operators and conversions.
>
> ...
>
> For constant expressions (expressions that can be fully evaluated at compile time), the default overflow checking context is always `checked`. Unless a constant expression is explicitly placed in an `unchecked` context, overflows that occur during the compile-time evaluation of the expression always cause compile-time errors.

Comment: Though this is not raising any exception, the value of state won't be changed to -1, whereas in C++ it is not so.